# Pull elements from a list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
["Sports","Soccer","Cricket","Food","Noodles","Cake","Burger","Country","US","UK","China"]
```

I want to make a dictionary with keys bring Sports, Food and Country

All the sports always follow list item "Sports" until "Food" and all list items always follow "Food" and so on and the "Sports", "Food" & "Country" do not reappear.

So the category is the key and its relative items are the values

Like below

```
cleaned_output = {
    "Sports" : ["Soccer","Cricket"],
    "Food" : ["Noodles","Cake","Burger"],                   
    "Country" : ["US","UK","China"]
}
```

I tried doing it but was only ending up having multiple loops, please help how can I do it in a short way.

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't anything built-in for this, and Stack Overflow is not for code review.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Then what is it for?

Comment: For specific questions regarding code that doesn't yet meet requirements (either because it crashes, produces wrong output, is unacceptably slow...). But even if you wanted your code reviewed, we would have to see it first. My suggestion is to read the FAQ/tour info at https://codereview.stackexchange.com and see if you can ask a good question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with a single loop over the list. The key idea is to remember which group you are currently adding to and update that each time you come to a new group. If each key will only appear once, you could do it like this:

```
data = [
    "Sports", "Soccer", "Cricket",
    "Food", "Noodles", "Cake", "Burger", 
    "Country", "US", "UK", "China"
]
cleaned_output = {
    "Sports": [],
    "Food": [],
    "Country": []
}
for item in data:
    if item in results:
        # item is a group name; update current group
        group = item
    else:
        # regular item; add to list for current group
        cleaned_output[group].append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list of the keys, and find the index of the current key in the data list and index of the next key (length of data list if current is the last key), then just take the slice between the index values from the data list.

```py
data=["Sports","Soccer","Cricket","Food","Noodles","Cake","Burger","Country","US","UK","China"]
keys = ["Sports", "Food", "Country" ]
out = {}
for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
    currIndex = data.index(key)
    nextIndex = data.index(keys[idx+1]) if idx<(len(keys)-1) else len(data)
    out.update({key: data[currIndex+1:nextIndex]})
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
{'Sports': ['Soccer', 'Cricket'],
 'Food': ['Noodles', 'Cake', 'Burger'],
 'Country': ['US', 'UK', 'China']}
```

Comment: This would have bad performance when there come some large datas.

Comment: It has O(k*n) performance, where k is the number of keys and n is the length of `data`. The best solution has O(n) performance. On the other hand, this does most of the iteration in C (searching the list and transferring items from `data` to the output). So it may outperform mine if k is small.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

data=["Sports","Soccer","Cricket","Food","Noodles","Cake","Burger","Country","US","UK","China"]
keys = {"Sports", "Food", "Country" }

item_list = [[*v] for _, v in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x in keys)]
d = {k[0]: v for k, v in zip(*(iter(item_list), ) * 2)}
```

Time complexity `O(n)`